# How to retrieve bioportal mappings using SPARQL

Tags: sparql, rdf

Is there a way to query the bioportal mappings?

Say I have `<http://purl.bioontology.org/ontology/UATC/V10BX02>` in my graph, and I would like to pull additional information from MeSH. I'm not having much luck with the API, which is likely user error.

Comment: use the BioPortal SPARQL endpoint or not? I don't understand what you're asking, either use the SPARQL endpoint or just the REST service. Both are online.

Comment: @AKSW I didn't know there was a sparql endpoint for mapping.

Comment: ah, ok. I though you knew because you also added the `sparql` tag. Good hat you found the answer in the end. Don't forget to accept your own answer to mark the question solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this website which has examples on how to query mappings between ontologies.

http://sparql.bioontology.org/examples